# Visual Studio 2019 MFC App: How do I read from a text file and display the strings in different fields/Edit Controls?

Tags: c++, file, mfc

let's say I have a 'user.txt' file that has three lines:

```
35
160
green
```

and in Visual Studio 2019 mfc app project I have three fields:

```
txtUserAge
txtUserWeight
txtUserFavoriteColor
```

**How would I read each line from the User.txt file so that it fills out the corresponding Edit Controls?**

What I've done so far is the opposite, for saving to a file:

1. right click Edit Control, Add Variable
2. set `txtUserAge`, for instance, as a Value category of C-String type variable named `userAgeVar`
3. In my main .cpp , on Save button click, have a `CString newAge = userAgeVar;`
4. Then to convert CString to string `CT2CA ct (newAge);  string strNewAge(ct);`
5. Then send it to a class

```
StatSaver user1;
user1.recordStats(strNewAge);
```

6. Where the class has:

```
void StatSaver::recordStats(string ageString)
{
  ofstream outFile;
  outFile << ageString << "\n";
  outFile.close();
}
```

I just can't seem to think in reverse on this to read the same text file and fill out the fields/edit controls. I'd appreciate any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: You might want to look into the CArchive class. MFC would have you create a CFIle object from which you can create a CArchive object which is feature rich and should have what you’re looking for in terms of reading and writing a file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was way simpler than I thought.  I linked it to a button,

```
void CMFCReadTextToBoxDlg::OnBnClickedbtnread()
{
    ifstream MyReadFile("user.txt");
    string textRead1;
    string textRead2;
    string textRead3;
    string textRead4;

    getline(MyReadFile, textRead1);
    CString cs1(textRead1.c_str());
    SetDlgItemText(txtField1, cs1);

    getline(MyReadFile, textRead2);
    CString cs2(textRead2.c_str());
    SetDlgItemText(txtField2, cs2);

    getline(MyReadFile, textRead3);
    CString cs3(textRead3.c_str());
    SetDlgItemText(txtField3, cs3);

    getline(MyReadFile, textRead4);
    CString cs4(textRead4.c_str());
    SetDlgItemText(txtField4, cs4);
    
    
    MyReadFile.close();
    
}
```